# Iterate all items in Firestore collection by key with pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I thought this one would be easier but it's not happening so far. I would like to iterate through all items in a collection without downloading every single item in one go.

Suppose my collection is at the ref `/users` and each user entry has a key as a username, such that you end up with

```
/users/
       jonsmith89: {}
       janedoe_: {}
       ...
```

I don't have a field to `orderBy()` since there are embedded collections contained in those objects and as such the docs for [Pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) are not helping me. This is what I have so far

```
async IterateCollection(path, dataFunction, limit = 10) {
    let collection = this.db.collection(path)
        .limit(limit);

    let current = collection;
    let entries = 0;

    do {
        let snapshot = await current.get();

        // Do something with snapshot.docs......

        let last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
        current = collection.startAfter(last.data())

        entries = snapshot.size;
    } while (entries > 0);
}
```

what I get is an exception:

> Too many cursor values specified. The specified values must match the orderBy() constraints of the query.

Which kind of makes sense, but how can I order it by id(key) then? I tried a blank `orderBy()` as well as `orderBy('id')` even though there is no id field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `startAfter` method needs the `DocumentSnapshot`, not the `data`.

```
startAfter(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot): Query;
```

So you have to remove the `.data()`

```
current = collection.startAfter(last)
```